# Are forward rolls dangerous for young children?

Tags: toddler, activities

My 2.5 year old is fascinated by forward rolls and attempts to do them on the floor and on the bed. He is not afraid of hurting himself, he also dives head first into the bed and such. 
I worry about him injuring his neck, because he is fearless and strong, and because his head is still so large so he cannot tuck it in as much as i can.

However, i have not been able to find any reliable information online about toddlers and the risks of forward rolls.

Comment: I have no scientific evidence to provide, but in my neighborhood, gymnastics lessons at the competitive club can start at 36 months, and they do rolls and cartwheels when ready. My own kids were right about 36 months when they became interested.

Comment: by "forward roll", do you mean "[somersault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somersault)"?

Comment: @warren somersault's are done in the air, when the (head and) back touch the floor i believe it's a forward roll - i think.

Comment: @Ivana - maybe it's a regional thing .. always heard them called somersaults when I was a kid :)

Comment: I don't have an answer, but try and teach him to tuck his chin to minimise strain on the cervical spine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a daycare provider for the last 10 years, specializing in Infant and Toddler care, this is pretty normal. Kids that age love to roll, tumble and try new ways to move around. As long as you are providing a safe environment and there to monitor what's going on, I wouldn't lose any sleep over it. This is large motor skill development, have fun!!!